# Шаблоны классов и экземпляры их статических переменных

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, статические-члены

Допустим, есть шаблон класса:

```
template<typename T>
class Link
{
public:
    Link(std::vector<T*> vars = std::vector<T*>()) : _vars(vars)
    {
    };
    ~Link() {};

private:
    std::vector<T*> _vars{};
};
```

Далее, я хочу иметь доступ ко всем экземплярам класса Link каждого типа в отдельности.
Я создаю статическую переменную links - контейнер, который заполняю в конструкторе (или это плохой подход?):

```
template<typename T>
class Link
{
public:
    static std::vector<Link*> links;

    Link(std::vector<T*> vars = std::vector<T*>()) : _vars(vars)
    {
        links.push_back(this);
    };
    ~Link() {};

    void job()
    {
        /* тут я могу обрабатывать все экземпляры Link конкретного типа */
    }

private:
    std::vector<T*> _vars{};
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<Link<T>*> Link<T>::links = std::vector<Link<T>*>();
```

Теперь я могу обрабатывать экземпляры каждого типа в отдельности, что мне и нужно. Но как мне перебрать все созданные экземпляры Link::links ? Т.е. как в данном примере перебрать все экземпляры Link<int> и Link<double> и всех созданных типов, я ведь не знаю, в общем случае, какие типы были созданы из шаблона?

```
int main()
{
    Link<int> L1{};
    Link<int> L2{};
    auto L3 = Link(std::vector<int*>());

    Link<double> L4{};
    Link<double> L5{};

    for (const auto& L : Link<int>::links)
    {
        /* все, что нужно, я могу сделать в Link::job() */
    }

    for (const auto& L : Link</*ALL*/>::links)
    {
        /* как перебрать все созданные экземпляры vector<Link> links ??? */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

UPD:
Пришла идея, что можно создать базовый класс LinkBase, в нем так же создать статический контейнер для всех Link<>, а Link отнаследовать от LinkBase... Но как-то много лишнего?

Comment: Не понял... вы хотите а одном векторе хранить экземпляры для разных типов T? (Кстати, вас не смущает, что вы при копировании в вектор создаете новые экземпляры-копии? :)) Это же разные типы, по сути никак не связанные...

Comment: @Harry нет, в векторах хранятся экземпляры одного типа. Я хочу получить доступ ко всем созданным переменным links, т.е. как в данном примере перебрать все экземпляры Link<int> и Link<double> и всех созданных типов, я ведь не знаю, в общем случае, какие типы были созданы из шаблона? (по поводу экземпляров-копий - не соображу - в каком месте, уже вечер пример создавал с нуля на скорую руку :)

Comment: В простейшем  виде это будет суровое нордическое type erasure, и надо будет городить дичайшую RTTI, например. А главное, зачем? В конце концов, есть Питон.

Comment: @Harry сообразил :)) это не так важно для данного вопроса.

Comment: Вы лучше напишите, что вы собираетесь делать при этом переборе, а то этот вопрос смахивает на проблему XY.

Comment: @user7860670 хочу разом обработать все созданные экземпляры Link не зависимо от типа, который они хранят. Допустим, вывести в консоль

Comment: вы осознаете, что `Link<int>` и `Link<double>` являются неродственными классами и для каждого из них придется писать свой блок кода в котором используется их статический тип? Чтобы работать с ними в единообразной манере, делайте интерфейс с соотв. виртуальными функциями и регистрируйте и перебирайте его.

Comment: @ да, похоже, начинаю понимать. Ваш вариант я уже в апдейте написал. В итоге получится - один общий контейнер, плюс по контейнеру на каждый тип? Т.е. других альтернатив нет?

Comment: Через базовый тип - да, можно: тогда типы становятся связанными через предка.   Пожалуй, это наилучший в смысле типизации способ. Хранить только нужно указатели, а не копии объектов, иначе будет срезка.

Comment: @Harry наверно, лучше shared_ptr, и создать функцию - фабрику? А то получается, что в моем примере - При выходе из области видимости - переменные L1, L2, ... уничтожатся, и в векторах будут invalid pointers?

Comment: Можно и так. Главное, что я хотел сказать - не хранить копии объектов. А как это делать - возможны варианты :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пришел к такому решению. Возможно, кому-то из новичков (как я) пригодится. А экспертам - для развлечения покритиковать :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::array;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

enum class TYPE
{
    CONTACT,
    FLOW,
    INOUT
};

struct fluid
{
    static const vector<pair<TYPE, string>> entrails;
};

const vector<pair<TYPE, string>> fluid::entrails = {
        {TYPE::CONTACT, "P"},
        {TYPE::FLOW,    "Q"},
        {TYPE::CONTACT, "conc"}
};

struct thermo
{
    static const vector<pair<TYPE, string>> entrails;
};

const vector<pair<TYPE, string>> thermo::entrails = {
        {TYPE::CONTACT, "T"},
        {TYPE::CONTACT, "heat"}
};

struct electro
{
    static const vector<pair<TYPE, string>> entrails;
};

const vector<pair<TYPE, string>> electro::entrails = {
        {TYPE::CONTACT, "P"},
        {TYPE::FLOW, "I"}
};

/*****************************************************************************/

class BaseLink
{
    static vector<BaseLink*> ALL_LINKS;
public:

    ~BaseLink() {};

    BaseLink(const BaseLink&) = delete;
    BaseLink(BaseLink&&) = delete;
    BaseLink& operator=(const BaseLink&) = delete;
    BaseLink& operator=(BaseLink&&) = delete;

    static vector<BaseLink*> all_links();

    virtual size_t dimension() const
    {
        return _entrails_vars.size();
    }

    virtual size_t count() const = 0;
    virtual vector<string> names() const = 0;

protected:
    BaseLink()
    {
        ALL_LINKS.push_back(this);
    };

    vector<double>_entrails_vars{};
};

vector<BaseLink*> BaseLink::ALL_LINKS = vector<BaseLink*>();

vector<BaseLink*> BaseLink::all_links()
{
    return BaseLink::ALL_LINKS;
}

/*****************************************************************************/
template<typename T>
class Link: public BaseLink
{
    static vector<Link*> links;
public:

    Link(const std::initializer_list<T>& vars) : BaseLink(), _vars(vars)
    {
        _entrails_vars.resize(T::entrails.size());
        links.push_back(this);
    };
    ~Link() {};

    static vector<Link*> get_links();

    vector<string> names() const override 
    {
        vector<string> names{};
        for (const auto& [type, name] : T::entrails)
            names.push_back(name);

        return names;
    }

    size_t count() const override
    {
        return _vars.size();
    }

    void job()
    {
        /* тут я могу обрабатывать все экземпляры Link конкретного типа */
    }

private:
    vector<T> _vars{};
};

template<typename T>
vector<Link<T>*> Link<T>::links = vector<Link<T>*>();

template<typename T>
vector<Link<T>*> Link<T>::get_links()
{
    //return links; // СМУЩАЕТ, НО РАБОТАЕТ
    return Link<T>::links;
}


int main()
{
    /* 
     * переменные fluid, thermo, electro создаются где-то в приложении 
     * тут просто заполняем дефолтными значениями для теста
     */
    auto L1 = Link({fluid{}, fluid{}});
    auto L2 = Link({ fluid{} });
    auto L3 = Link({ thermo{} , thermo{} , thermo{} });
    auto L4 = Link({ thermo{} , thermo{} , thermo{} , thermo{} });
    auto L5 = Link({ thermo{} , thermo{} });
    auto L6 = Link({ electro{} , electro{} , electro{} });

    std::cout << "ALL LINKS:\n";
    for (const auto& link : BaseLink::all_links())
    {
        std::cout << "\tdimension = " << link->dimension() 
            << "; count = " << link->count() << ": names [";
        for (const auto& name : link->names())
            std::cout << name << ' ';
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    std::cout << "fluid LINKS:\n";
    for (const auto& link : Link<fluid>::get_links())
    {
        std::cout << "\tdimension = " << link->dimension()
            << "; count = " << link->count() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "thermo LINKS:\n";
    for (const auto& link : Link<thermo>::get_links())
    {
        std::cout << "\tdimension = " << link->dimension()
            << "; count = " << link->count() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "electro LINKS:\n";
    for (const auto& link : Link<electro>::get_links())
    {
        std::cout << "\tdimension = " << link->dimension()
            << "; count = " << link->count() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
ALL LINKS:
    dimension = 3; count = 2: names [P Q conc ]
    dimension = 3; count = 1: names [P Q conc ]
    dimension = 2; count = 3: names [T heat ]
    dimension = 2; count = 4: names [T heat ]
    dimension = 2; count = 2: names [T heat ]
    dimension = 2; count = 3: names [P I ]
fluid LINKS:
    dimension = 3; count = 2
    dimension = 3; count = 1
thermo LINKS:
    dimension = 2; count = 3
    dimension = 2; count = 4
    dimension = 2; count = 2
electro LINKS:
    dimension = 2; count = 3
```

Comment: Как минимум, из `BaseLink::all_links()` и прочих стоит возвращать ссылки на вектор... Вероятно константные...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за замечание.