# Генерация значения аргумента шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть шаблон класса:

```
template<short modelID>
class Model
{
public:
    static constexpr short STID = modelID;

    Model() {};
};
```

При создании экземпляров Model я указываю modelID:

```
auto model0 = Model<0>();

auto model1 = Model<1>();
auto model10 = Model<1>();
```

Или могу даже так:

```
auto model11 = Model<decltype(model1)::STID>();
```

Узнал про такую штуку - [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), но после первого-второго прочтения пока не могу понять - возможно ли создавать экземпляры не указывая аргумент шаблона, а чтобы он генерировался сам? Т.е. чтобы можно было написать:

```
auto model0 = Model();

auto model1 = Model();

auto model10 = Model<decltype(model1)::STID>();
auto model11 = Model<decltype(model1)::STID>();
```

А результат был такой же.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а какой должен аргумент по умолчанию? Как вычисляться?

Comment: обычный инкремент - если не указан аргумент шаблона

Comment: Ну и на основе какой информации вот тут выводить? `auto model0 = Model();` Вот вы - компилятор; опишите свои действия... :)

Comment: Ух. Это возможно, но очень-очень сложно. Посмотрите [unconstexpr-cpp20](https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr-cpp20) и [unconstexpr](https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr).

Comment: @Harry нужен какой-то counter времени компиляции как я понимаю... но т.к. 
первый шаблон я написал на прошлой неделе, то пока в голове в итоге какая-то рекурсия по этому вопросу

Comment: Тогда лучше оставьте эту идею. Счетчики времени компиляции и подобные вещи (это называется stateful template metaprogramming) - это чуть ли не самая сложная часть шаблонов (а может и всего С++).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat т.е. это, в принципе, возможно?

Comment: Ну вот я ссылки кинул, там такое сделано.

Comment: ассоциация: [template with lambda as unique default parameter on each instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410522/template-with-lambda-as-unique-default-parameter-on-each-instantiation)

Comment: @user7860670 параметр шаблона - функция? о_О. Так тоже можно? Очень круто

Comment: можно так или нет - это еще большой вопрос, по идее нет, но это не точно

Comment: ок, а если это не инкремент, а сгенерированное уникальное значение?

Comment: @hermann.minkowski, использование шаблонов здесь это самоцель?

Comment: @Fat-Zer в Model есть переменные классов со статическими переменными. Я хотел, чтобы для каждого экземпляра Model создавались отдельные статические переменные... Да и вообще, разделить внутренности каждого экземпляра. Плохая идея?

Comment: @hermann.minkowski, просто зачем нужны статические члены, которые по определению **общие** для всех экземпляров класса, если для каждого экземпляра они **свои**? если это какая-то оптимизация, то она звучит как крайне преждевременная... а так мне не хватает фантазии, где это могло бы пригодится... точнее есть идеи, но это сильно отличается от use-case'ов в примере...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ок, есть шаблонный класс Link<typename VarType>, после создания всех возможных экземпляров Link надо их обработать - но надо создать контейнеры всех экземпляров для каждого VarType в отдельности - реализованы как статические переменные. Например, граф, с вершинами разных цветов, цвет это VarType, Link соединяет эти вершины, но одного цвета. В итоге Link<Red> содержит статический контейнер со всеми Link соединяющими красные вершины. Но для каждого экземпляра Model(в данном примере - для разных графов) -  должны быть разные контейнеры :)

Comment: @Fat-Zer уверен, что архитектура не идеальная, по неопытности... т.к. сам сомневаюсь в правильности такого решения... но это уже вариант чуть ли не пятый :)

Comment: @Fat-Zer  да и, возможно, это важно, заранее я не знаю, сколько и какие цвета будут. Был вариант без шаблонов - но там много проверок на цвет, рассортировки... подумал, что раскидав их по классам - сэкономлю кучу циклов

Comment: я не вижу особых причин всё здесь шаблонизировать: можно сделать внешние keeper'ы-одиночки, можно инкапсулировать создание объектов... из подозрительного `Link<typename VarType>` и `Link<Red>` — как-то не вяжутся... я ожидал тип Link<Color>, где Color будет каким-нить enum'ом, а конкретный цвет обычным членом... в общем можно в отдельном вопросе обсудить это с конкретными интерфейсами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer цвета я привел для упрощения описания, на самом деле это самостоятельные классы. Спасибо за помощь, попробую создать более конкретный пример с реализованными интерфейсами... но уже так много написано кода, что надо подумать над таким примером :)

Comment: @Fat-Zer кстати, прототип реализации Link есть в моем же вопросе, там о общий интерфейс показан https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1192735/337451

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115349/discussion-on-question-by-hermann-minkowski----).